# Model Service ChannelEntry relationship fields

Tags: channel-entries, ee4, channel-entries-api

I can't figure out how to save (or retrieve) relationship field data using the Model Service. I can save flat fields with out an issue (and retrieve them).

So when retrieving an entry like this:

```
$entry = ee('Model')
        ->get('ChannelEntry')
        ->filter('channel_id', 1)
        ->first();

var_dump($entry->field_id_1); // this is a text field data, this works

var_dump($entry->field_id_2); // this is a relationship field with data, it outputs NULL
```

As you can see, I don't get the relationship data. I couldn't figure out a way to load relationship data either, by using `->with("Relationships")`or any other verbiage that makes sense.

At the same time, I can't seem to save relationship data in any way:

```
$entry = ee('Model')->make('ChannelEntry');

$entry->title = "Title";
$entry->url_title = "title";
$entry->site_id = 1;
$entry->channel_id = 1;
$entry->status = "open";
$entry->author_id = 1;
$entry->field_id_1 = "My text field"; // this works
$entry->field_id_2 = array("100", "101"); // doesn't save relatoinship data, and trying a few different formats didn't work
$entry->save();
```

I've been digging through the EE source code and it isn't clear if this is possible at all. I know I could insert raw DB entries next to the Model Service, but that sucks and is harder to get right.

Any one have any success with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I too had the same issue, the EE documentation to put it nicely is rather incomplete on this topic.  Looking though the source I saw an example in ft.relationships.php:

```
ee('Model')->get('ChannelEntry', $entry_id)
                    ->with('Children', 'Channel')
                    ->fields('Channel.channel_title', 'Children.entry_id', 'Children.title', 'Children.channel_id')
                    ->first()
                    ->Children;
```

This will give you just the child relationship entries, so you could foreach your entries to get each entry's children.  Not very satisfactory!

Comment: Wow. Thank you for your help! But `Not very satisfactory!` is crazy accurate. I was more importantly looking to figure out how to save a new entry with a relationship field, and there is no example of that in the `ft.relationships.php` file, so maybe that isn't possible, as it looks like saving a relationship field is all db inserts. I ended up just using a `batch_insert()`, but that didn't make a very happy developer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can save relationship data using below **Model** query. In below code `$entry->field_id_2` indicates the relationship data.

```
$entry = ee('Model')->make('ChannelEntry');
$entry->channel_id = 'your_channel_id';
$entry->site_id =  ee()->config->item('site_id');
$entry->author_id = ee()->session->userdata('member_id');
$entry->ip_address = ee()->session->userdata['ip_address'];
$entry->status = "open";
$entry->sticky = FALSE;
$entry->title = 'your_entry_title';
$entry->url_title = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", "-", 'your_entry_url_title');
$entry->field_id_2 = array('data'=>array("100", "101")); //ids of related entry
$entry->entry_date = ee()->localize->now;
$entry->edit_date = ee()->localize->now;
$entry->save();
```

Well, as far as I know there is no any method to fetch relationship data using **Model**. Because, as you should know relationship is third-party Addon. But you can get data of relationship from `exp_relationships` using below simple query.

```
$entry = ee()->db->get_where('exp_relationships', array('parent_id'=>'your_parent_entry_id'));
var_dump($entry->result());
```

I hope this will helps you.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but the Relationships field is a **first party-addon** that ships with EE2/3/4/5. https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/tree/stability/system/ee/EllisLab/Addons/relationship
But that is really good information about how to save data to a relationship field in an EE Entry Model, although I haven't tested your answer. The answer I accepted shows how to retrieve it from an EE Entry Model. I wish I could give you both the points.